# MVC3 Ajax - Submit checkbox to form returns a blank page with the checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, checkbox

I tried to submit my form with a button and everything worked (the controller was call and the POST worked fine). Then I add a checkbox right next to it, and it returns a blank page with only the checkbox on it when I click it.
Im using:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js")" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusiveajax.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Part of my views (im using partial view):
Index.cshtml:

```
<td id="ProjectFieldset">
     @Html.Partial("_ProjectSelect") 
</td>
```

_ProjectSelect.cshtml :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("test", "Project", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "ProjectFieldset" }))
         {
        <td>
            @Html.CheckBox("ckboxItem", true , new {onchange="this.form.submit();"})
            <input type="submit" value="allo" id="allo" />
        </td>
         }
```

Controller:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult test(bool ckboxItem)
    {
        ViewData["projects"] = db.Projects;
        return PartialView("_ProjectSelect");
    }
```

This is just a part of my code. There is no HTML error. 
So, the checkbox and the button are well displayed, and when press the button, everything works. When I click the checkbox, it goes in the controller, but after that, it display a blank page. Any help here ??? Thks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusiveajax.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Notice the typo that you have in your `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script name.

Also `jquery 1.4.4` is kinda old now. I would recommend you using a more recent version.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, the typo is not in my code, it happens when I wrote this. What version of jquery would you suggest me ? Btw, I have replace the checkbox by a radio button, and it does the same thing. It seems that the button is the only one that works fine.